# Capture Images of Rotating Object Automation

Tags: scripting, export, transforms

I have a 3D object (ball) that I want to capture a data set from.

---

Ideally, I want to start with the ball at some orientation  (0,0), then rotate the ball by **5** **degree** **icrements** and capture a 2D (jpg) of the object and the rotation coordinates, creating a complete image set of every n degree angle viewpoint of the ball.

The end goal is to an image and rotation coordinate of the ball from *every* 5 deg angle possible.

Additionally, this would need to be automated, to avoid having to manually capture 20K images.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you ever watch some basic animation tutorials? there are tons of good and free animation tutorials on yt....

Comment: Yeah you would literally just set your scene frames to 72 frames (360/5) and then set a keyframe on frame 1 to zero degrees rotation and another on frame 72 to 360 degrees. Then render an image sequence and each frame should result in a image captured of the object rotated 5 degrees.

Comment: "The end goal is to an image and rotation coordinate of the ball from every 5 deg angle possible."  There are an infinite number of such rotations, because there are an infinite number of axes along which to rotate in 5 degree angles.  Are you looking for every 5 deg rotation in a single rotational axis?

Comment: @Nathan looking to do 0,0 -> 0,5 -> 0,10... 0,275. then 5,0 -> 5,5 -> 5,10...etc. Want the images to be a set of all 5 deg rotations on all 5 deg axis changes from 1 standing viewpoint

Comment: @Chris yeah I'll check out yt - heard it's good and free also thanks man

Comment: @Jakemoyo that was my plan - wasn't sure if I needed some python script to get my there. Trying to capture the coordinates for each image as well, but I'm sure I can get it from the anim. sequence. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, capturing images of an object rotating is-- just a render.  The only trick is getting the rotation values we want, as easily as we can get them.  We can make this pretty easy by using fcurve modifiers.

With some simple arithmetic, we can find there are 72 groups of 5 degree divisions in 360 degrees, so we'll need 72*72 = 5184 frames of animation.

We'll need to work with the graph editor viewport.  We'll start with an object with an XYZ Euler transform, and, on frame 0 (not frame 1) we'll manually enter a rotation of -180 degrees in X and Z fields, and keyframe rotation.  We'll jump to frame 5184 and enter a rotation of 180 degrees of X rotation and keyframe rotation, then, *delete the Z rotation keyframe for frame 5184.*  We'll jump to frame 72 and give it a rotation of 180 degrees of Z rotation, *then, delete the X rotation keyframe for frame 72.*  Finally, we'll set the interpolation mode for all channels to linear.  Our graph editor should look something like this:

[image]

We only have Z rotation definitions from frames 0 to 72, and we want to repeat those, so we can give our Z rotation channel a *cycles* modifier, which will repeat the rotation:

[image]

Don't worry about the drawing of the graph.  You can see I set it to cycle 72 times, only after the existing keyframes, but that's not strictly necessary-- you can use defaults if you want, this is just a cleaner display of what we're doing.

Now let's hide the Z channel and look at our X channel.  Here, we want the x rotation clamped to intervals of 5 degrees, so let's give it a stepped interpolation modifier:

[image]

It takes 72 frames to rotate 5 degrees, so I set the step to 72 frames.

We could step our Z rotation, since we don't want to draw between values there either, but our step size would be 1 because of how we've set this up, so it's not necessary.  We're only ever going to render images with values that are even multiples of 5 degrees anyways.

Finally, we need to work on our label.  I made the label with a geometry nodes object:

[image]

I created my driver for my value node just by typing #frame into the value node; now I can use it for math to determine my values.  You can see that I'm essentially duplicating the math that I used to derive my rotation values (and indeed, another way to do this would have been to use this math for drivers for X and Z rotation channels, rather than keyframing.)  Why not just drive from the keyframed values?  Because the keyframed values don't include the f-curve modifiers.  Why not drive from transform channels?  Because there are multiple Euler representations of singular orientations (ie, Euler angles are *aliased*), and Blender won't necessarily give us the representation we were expecting.

(I should have put a "fill curve" node in there at the end to give the text faces.)

All that's left here is to render.  We've set things up such that our last frame is the same as our 0th frame, so we want to render starting from frame 1 to avoid duplication.  If we render to an image sequence, we'll have 5184 images, each representing a unique angle that you want, in total representing *all* the angles you want, and each labelled with that angle in the image.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer much appreciated. I think this will do it for sure - I’ll play around on my side and hopefully get the results 